# XNA Game networking on a host PC and a virtual one

Tags: xna

I'm relatively new to c# and the XNA, but using several tutorials and books I succeed at creating a simple game. The problem is, that i have only one computer and i want to test the game's networking features. So i have installed VMware Workstation and created a Virtual PC running Windows 7 Professional x86. On my host PC I'm running Windows 7 x64. I bridged both PC's and now i can share files between them flawlessly. But unfortunately when i run my game on both of them, create a session on the first, it seems that the second can't find and join that session. I tried to run another games like Quake and the result was the same - it looked like both PC's don't see each other. I also tried with installing Hamachi on both machines - no result again.
So my question is - is it possible to run XNA game which uses Windows Live for creating and joining a session on a host PC and virtual one.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you ping each computer from the other? Maybe there's some security measure that's keeping you from being able to reach it. A VM should work just as any other machine, shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to use bridged networking in VM settings.

you can then specify different IP's  on host / guest.

Also, try to stick it with IPv6

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to test networking features and not simulate lag you can run multiple clients on 1 computer.
You should be able to find the session just the same as if you were running over the net/Lan.

***Note:***

Personally I've only done networking with Lidgren's network library so I'm not sure if using XNA's built in library works the same but it could be worth a try.

***Edit:***

Thought it was worth mentioning if you're running in the editor it won't let you run multiple clients directly, so publish your game to a local folder and run from there. You can also run one from the editor to get any debug messages or exceptions that occur.